# How to transpile external dependency in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, babeljs

I have an angular-cli application and i use [Angular IMask Plugin](https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/tree/gh-pages/plugins/angular). Angular IMask Plugin wraps vanila imaskjs which has "package.module" in es2015 format alongside
 with "package.main" in es5 umd format. While building angular-cli takes "package.module" but does not transpile it with babel and therefore my app does not work in IE.

How can i configure angular-cli to include imaskjs to be transpiled?
It could be solved in webpack like this https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs/issues/24
But what about angular-cli? Is eject is the only solution?

Is it ok to distribute "package.module" in es2015 format for libraries or it should be in es5 as well?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?